# CSS not recognizing one my linked fonts

Tags: css, font-family

In CSS, I'm linking to two local fonts. Only one is being recognized currently and I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'The Rainmaker';
    src: url('The Rainmaker.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Timeline';
    src: url('Timeline.ttf');
}
```

Comment: Which one is not recognised? If it's the rainmaker font, remove the space in the file name.

Comment: Yes, it is the rainmaker font but, I was using it before and it was working with the space as long as i had quotes. I changed something and it stopped accepting it. Now when I copy the whole font-face for the rainmaker and paste it, it accepts one but still doesn't accept the other so the syntax must be right

Comment: Have you tried to debug with some dev tools for your browser? Are you getting 404 for the font?

Comment: Do you have  the file 'The rainmaker.otf' in the same folder as css file

Comment: @nickkasamis than you must check the path to the font file. if your fonts are inside `css/fonts/Tmeline.otf` and your stylesheet is inside `css/style.css` than the path should be `fonts/Timeline.ttf` - And yes, remove the space in any case.

Comment: Yes the font is in the same folder as the stylesheet. The font was working before and then i something else and it stopped working. I just kept undoing until sublime accepted it again. So it's working now. Thank you all.

Comment: Just a recommendation, use git so you know the stages the project is and if something like  this happens you are able to get the old code with out Ctrl + Z(UNDO)

Comment: Do you have this only in a local server or there is any URL to check the site with WEB Tools!!!!

Comment: @nickkasamis
So I have the same thing, so after I make it work I change the file from one directory to another and also change the src: url() and the font just stop working. The solution for me was to **clear the cache**.